How to install DisplayLink-Driver on Ubuntu 24.04.01 LTS?
i've just upgraded my PC from Ubuntu 24.04 LTS to 24.04.01 and DisplayLink stopped working.
Driver was from Synaptic official APT repo, but now apt says it can't find candidate.
When I try to install standalone version I have a message:
Code:
Verifying archive integrity...  100%   MD5 checksums are OK. All good.
Uncompressing DisplayLink Linux Driver 6.0.0  100%  
Distribution discovered: No LSB modules are available.
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
'evdi' Debian package appears to be installed.
This installer is incompatible with the packaged driver.

installed evdi:
evdi/now 1.14.7-109 amd64 [installed,local]
How to proceed now ?

It happened that it was enough to install
evdi-dkms package and continue with displaylink standalone installer.
Another useful resource if you have problems with evdi https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/18hbbf7/comment/kd5uqyw/

My problem was not getting my Dell D6000 to display all four monitors.
The problem - when I went back into the 23.01 problem resolution was the DisplayLink D6000 package.
I went to the DisplayLink site, downloaded the latest package for 24.04.1.
Installed the DisplayLink 6.1 evdi-dkms package for 24.04.01,
I now have all four monitors working perfectly again!  Happy!
